# Is it possible to conditionally control isAmp through the server?

Tags: next.js, amp-html

UPDATE:
I'll rephrase my question since it's not clear enough.
What I want to accomplish here is pass isAmp from getInitialProps to the component to control whether it'll be amp or a regular one.

Why I want to do that?
Because I want to make some client operations if the page is loading a deleted item; since amp is all done on the server, I can't use react hooks nor redirect the page after 10 seconds.
Hope this explains better.

I have an an amp page that I want to turn into a regular page when an item status(href="page/itemId") is deleted so I can use the client side to redirect the user after 10seconds.

To make a page amp, we just add this export at the top of the file

```
export const config = { amp: true };
```

The mode I'm interested in is the 'hybrid' mode.
Is there a way to pass the isAmp value through the server and then to the client like this next hook does

```
const isAmp = useAmp();
```

I want the value passed right to the first line of code above:

```
export const config = { amp: isAmp };
```

I'm going through this process in order to make client side code work, like redirecting the page to another url. Which only works on non-amp pages.

Comment: Omar, i've read this several times and have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: @JayGray 
Sorry about that. I meant to say that I want to pass isAmp from gitInitialProps to the component to control if the page is amp or not.

Answer (score 1):

From the doc you are not allowed to do the dynamic / conditional page configuration.

this is not allowed:

```
const test= somecondition ? true : 'hybrid'

export const config = {
    amp: test
}
```

see here:
https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/invalid-page-config

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/amp) says, use the `hybrid` mode.

```js
import {useAmp} from 'next/amp'

export const config = {amp: 'hybrid'} // Hybrid mode

function About(props) {
  const isAmp = useAmp()

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>My AMP About Page!</h3>
      {isAmp ? (
        <amp-img
          width="300"
          height="300"
          src="/my-img.jpg"
          alt="a cool image"
          layout="responsive"
        />
      ) : (
        <img width="300" height="300" src="/my-img.jpg" alt="a cool image" />
      )}
    </div>
  )
}

export default About
```

Comment: My explanation might be wrong, but I meant to say is that I want to pass isAmp from gitInitialProps to the component to control if the page is amp or not.

Comment: Also hybrid mode makes non-amp page the default unless append the ?amp=1 to the uri. In my case I want to maintain the default as AMP but control when to show the non-amp version of it.